# Evaluate an arbitrary symbolic expression given as a string at some values

Tags: r

I would like to let a user enter a string, for a formula for `y` as a function of `x`, e.g.

```
fn <- "x^2 + exp(3*x)"
```

I would then like to evaluate this expression at some points, e.g. for values of `x <- 1:0.1:100`.

I know I can do:

```
x <- 1:0.1:100
y <- eval(parse(text = fn))
```

However, this leaves my computer open to attacks if the user supplies `fn` which is not a formula

```
fn <- 'x; print("Your computer is compromised")'
```

Are there any alternative ways of achieving what I want to do?

Comment: I think there should be a way to do this with `substitute`/`parse`, but I can't work it out

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/package=RAppArmor

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One of R's coolest features is that it can process its own language, so you can create a function white list and check expressions against it:

```
# Function to check if an expression is safe
is_safe_call <- function(text, allowed.funs) {
  # Recursive function to evaluate each element in the user expression
  safe_fun <- function(call, allowed.funs) {
    if(is.call(call)) {
      call.l <- as.list(call)
      if(!is.name(call.l[[1L]]) || !as.character(call.l[[1L]]) %in% allowed.funs)
        stop(as.character(call.l[[1L]]), " is not an allowed function")
      lapply(tail(call.l, -1L), safe_fun, allowed.funs)
    }
    TRUE
  }
  # parse and call recursive function
  expr <- parse(text=text)
  if(length(expr) > 1L) stop("Only single R expressions allowed")
  safe_fun(expr[[1L]], allowed.funs)
}
```

We then define a whitelist of allowable functions.  It is very important that you are extremely careful about what you allow in here.  In particular, if you allow `parse`, `eval`, or any functions with possible unpleasant side effects (`system`, `unlink`, etc.) you open your system wide for attack.

```
allowed.funs <- c("+", "exp", "*", "^", "-", "sqrt")
```

And we test:

```
is_safe_call("x^2 + exp(3*x)", allowed.funs)
## [1] TRUE
is_safe_call("x^2 - sqrt(3*x)", allowed.funs)
## [1] TRUE
is_safe_call("unlink('~', recursive=TRUE)", allowed.funs)
## Error in safe_fun(parse(text = text)[[1L]], allowed.funs) : 
##   unlink is not an allowed function
is_safe_call("x + sqrt(unlink('~', recursive=TRUE))", allowed.funs)
## Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : unlink is not an allowed function
is_safe_call('x; print("Your computer is compromised")')
## Error in is_safe_call("x; print(\"Your computer is compromised\")") : 
##   Only single R expressions allowed
```

No waranties express or implied in this.  There may be a way to hack this that I haven't thought of, so don't put this on a public facing server without extensive scrutiny, but I think this might just work.

Note that if someone can provide an expression that somehow hacks `parse` itself, then you can be compromised that way.

---

EDIT: Ben Bolker suggested a clever trick to try to hack this, but this function is robust to that:

```
is_safe_call("exp <- function(...) system(\"echo do bad stuff\")", allowed.funs)
## Error in safe_fun(expr[[1L]], allowed.funs) :
##  <- is not an allowed function
allowed.funs <- c("+", "exp", "*", "^", "-", "sqrt", "<-")
is_safe_call("exp <- function(...) system(\"echo do bad stuff\")", allowed.funs)
## Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : function is not an allowed function
allowed.funs <- c("+", "exp", "*", "^", "-", "sqrt", "<-", "function")  
is_safe_call("exp <- function(...) system(\"echo do bad stuff\")", allowed.funs)
## Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : system is not an allowed function
```

Comment: this looks good. I thought another method would be to exploit `formula`, but I can't look at the underlying code of that.

Comment: but what about `exp <- function(...) system("echo do bad stuff")` ... ?  if you want to be safe, do you have to make sure that you're using `base::exp` ?

Comment: @BenBolker, this is not actually a concern since the expression `exp <- function(...) system("...")` fails the `is_safe_call` test (see edits)

Comment: @Alex that was my very first reaction, but no matter what you're going to have to evaluate the user's expression if you want to compute a value for it, so I think the only way to go is to make sure the expression is safe.